# Implementing Comparable with a generic class

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable, raw-types

I want to define a class that implements the generic Comparable interface. While in my class I also defined a generic type element `T`. In order to implement the interface, I delegate the comparison to `T`. Here is my code:

```
public class Item<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Item> {

    private int s;
    private T t;

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return getT().compareTo(o.getT());
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error information:

```
Item.java:11: error: method compareTo in interface Comparable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
        return getT().compareTo(o.getT());
                     ^
  required: T#1
  found: Comparable
  reason: actual argument Comparable cannot be converted to T#1 by method invocation conversion
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class Item
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Comparable
1 error
```

Can anybody tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but should this: `compareTo(Item o)` be `compareTo(Item<T> o)`?

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: You should select an answer for this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Item` (without any type argument) is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664), so:

1. We could pass any kind of `Item` to `Item.compareTo`. For example, this would compile:

   ```
   new Item<String>().compareTo(new Item<Integer>())
   ```
2. The method `o.getT()` returns `Comparable` instead of `T`, which causes the compilation error.

   In the example under the 1st point, after passing `Item<Integer>` to `Item.compareTo`, we would then erroneously pass an `Integer` to `String.compareTo`. The compilation error prevents us from writing the code which does that.

I think you just need to remove the raw types:

```
public class Item<T extends Comparable<T>>
implements Comparable<Item<T>> {

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item<T> o) {
        return getT().compareTo(o.getT());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You're using raw types in your class definition (`Item<T>` is generic, but you're omitting the type parameter `<T>`), change it to:

```
class Item<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Item<T>>
```

(Note the last `<T>`)

The `compareTo` method will then have to be changed as well:

```
public int compareTo(Item<T> o) { // again, use generics
    return getT().compareTo(o.getT());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this makes more sense. I have compiled and tested the following  :

```
class Item<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<E> {

 private int s;
 private E t;

 public E getE() {
     return t;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(E e) {
     return getE().compareTo(e);
 }

 public int compareTo(Item<E> other)
    {
        return getE().compareTo(other.getE());
    }

 }
```

Notice that you now need to have two compareTo methods.

Comment: The asker wants items to be comparable (by comparing their values).

Comment: It's possible if T implements Comparable, which is the case here.

Comment: Ya, please have a look at the other solution that I have given now.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make much sense at all. "we are extending comparable and not implementing it." - one implements interfaces and extends classes. `extends` is used in generics for both cases though. "because we are using a generic type T, we must not override compareTo method" - generic types don't prevent us from implementing interfaces, e.g. `ArrayList<T>` implements `List<T>`. "T can be anything [...] Specifically, it has to be something that is Comparable" - T already is `Comparable`, in both the OP's code and your code, in particular it is comparable to itself.

Comment: PLease have a look at the current answer, have changed it completely.

Comment: That's certainly better.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a related issue that I ran into, and couldn't find a concrete answer.

Suppose you have an interface

```
public interface myInt extends Comparable<myInt>
```

And a class `MyClass` that implements `myInt`.

Now you *only* want to compare `MyClass` with `MyClass` objects. How should we rewrite the interface and the class?

Answer:

```
public interface myInt<T extends myInt<T>> extends Comparable<T>
public class MyClass implements myInt<MyClass>
```